# trying to connect postgresql to go but I'm getting an error

Tags: postgresql, go

I've imported a module called "github.com/lib/pq". before I ran my code, I inserted this in the terminal % go get github.com/lib/pq. Then when i tried to run my code, I'm getting an error message in the terminal

> 'no required module provides package github.com/lib/pq: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'

Comment: I think you probably do need to read `go help modules` and then some introductory go and go module tutorials.

Comment: You didn't run `go mod init`. See [How to Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/code).

Answer (score 0):

Running `go mod tidy` will sync your go.mod and go.sum file with the imports in your code, this will add missing dependencies and remove unnecessary ones. Should solve your issue.